# error: (-215:Assertion failed) m.dims <= 2 in function 'FormattedImpl' in cv::dnn

Tags: c++, opencv, deep-learning, object-detection

I am loading a pre-trained TensorFlow model in the opencv dnn module using the following code -

```
cv::dnn::Net net = cv::dnn::readNetFromTensorflow("frozen_inference_graph.pb",
                                                   "graph.pbtxt");

net.setPreferableBackend(cv::dnn::DNN_BACKEND_CUDA); //Run model on GPU
net.setPreferableTarget(cv::dnn::DNN_TARGET_CUDA);

Mat image = imread("img.jpeg");
Mat resized;
cv::resize(image, resized, cv::Size(300, 300));
cout<<resized.size()<<endl;
cout<<"Resized"<<endl;
auto input_image = dnn::blobFromImage(image, 1.0, cv::Size(300, 300),
                                      cv::Scalar(127.5, 127.5, 127.5),
                                      false, false, CV_32F);
cout<<"Now setting Input";
net.setInput(input_image);
auto detections = net.forward();
cout<<detections;
return 0;
```

However the I get the following error as mentioned in the question -

```
what():  OpenCV(4.4.0) /home/atharva/opencv-4.4.0/modules/core/src/out.cpp:87: error: (-215:Assertion failed) m.dims <= 2 in function 'FormattedImpl'
```

Could someone please point out what the mistake is?. I believe there is some problem in BlobFromImage as nothing after it is getting printed.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs because you are trying to print a `cv::Mat` to standard output that has more than 2 dimensions.  With `cv::dnn`, the output after using `net.forward()` is 4-dimensional.  However I have no idea what model you are using because the output structure of the blob is different depending on what task you are trying to do.  If I had to guess you are doing some sort of object detection given your choice of variable names.  In that case, usually the first dimension is the batch size and since you are using only one image, the batch size is 1.  The second dimension is the number of channels in the output.  As you're doing object detection on the image, this will also be size 1.  The third and fourth dimensions are the number of rows and columns for the final output layer.

Going on faith, you can extract a 2D version of this `cv::Mat` to print out to standard output by doing:

```cpp
cv::Mat output(detections.size[2], detections.size[3], CV_32F, detection.ptr<float>());
```

Now that this is a 2D matrix, you can print out this instead by doing `std::cout << output << std::endl;`.

Comment: Thanks for replying @rayryeng. I indeed am trying to detect objects and was loading a pre-trained mobilenet SSD. However I am not printing `cv::Mat` anywhere except the last line, the `cout<<Now setting Input` is not getting printed as well.On a side not when I did `cout<<image` previously, it did print onto the std out(though it was all zeros i dont know why)..

Comment: Well removing the last line and running works now, Thanks a lot @rayryeng. But I still am not able to understand as to why the print statements after 'blobFromImage' were not working....

Comment: Remember that some operations on `cv::Mat`s are asynchronous so it probably got to the end of the program before it finished doing everything else.